# Adding controls dynamically without it being monotonous

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Firstly I cant think of a better title than this

Currently i have a method that creates controls dynamically from a switch statement.

The code is identical for each control except for the control itself.

Code:

```
            switch (control)
            {
                case "TextBox":
                    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                    txt.Name = "txt" + labeltext;
                    txt.Margin = _controlMargin;
                    txt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                    txt.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                    txt.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    break;
                case "ComboBox":
                    ComboBox cbo = new ComboBox();
                    cbo.Name = "cbo" + labeltext;
                    cbo.Margin = _controlMargin;
                    cbo.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                    cbo.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
                    cbo.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    break;
}
```

Is it possible to make the duplicate code into a method or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Delete all that and use proper XAML.

Comment: Why you need to create Controls dynamically in code behind? As mentioned above it is not good practice.

Comment: Is there any specific reasons you can't use `DataTemplate`s for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Control control = null;

switch (controlType)
{
   case "TextBox":
       control = new TextBox(); 
       control.Name = "txt + labelText;
       break; 
   case "ComboBox":
       control = new ComboBox(); 
       control.Name = "cbo" + labelText;
       break;
}

control.Margin = _controlMargin; 
control.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlighment.Stretch;
control.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
control.HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left
```

Comment: Your code goes against all accepted, well-known established good practices and patterns in WPF. -1

Comment: @HighCore please elaborate.

Comment: there's nothing to elaborate. in WPF, you use XAML to define the UI, not procedural code.

Comment: @HighCore Yes, that's the general rule but there are some cases where loading xaml with procedural code is beneficial such as creating UI elements at runtime.

Comment: that's what `DataTemplate`s are for. Creating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is bad practice. Period.

Comment: @HighCore You're right. Sorry, I haven't used Wpf in a while so I'm a bit rusty. When I have the time I'll edit my answer.